# Favorite websites with shortened hyperlinks

Tags: shortcode, links

Suppose in the site there are frequent links to another website, always tree same, say Wikipedia. Is there a way to write links to Wikipedia in a shortened way, and tell wordpress to translate it?

Example: something like `[wiki]/geography` shorthand for `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/geography`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you're looking for the [shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). That would enable you to write a short piece of code that does exactly what you want. As easy as this in your `functions.php`:

```
function wpse246274_wiki( $atts ) {
  $link = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" . $atts['link'];
  return $link;
  }
add_shortcode( 'wikilink', 'wpse246274_wiki' );
```

Which you would use like this in your post:

```
<a href="[wikilink link='geography']">Geography</a>
```

You could even leave out the attribute and just use

```
<a href="[wikilink]geography">Geography</a>
```

But that doesn't look as elegant.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have an additional question: what if I want a shortcode for *my* site URL, in a way that does not depend on the actual URL?  (using get_site_url() maybe?) Would it be possible?